# Python UTF-8 error while deploying sam using visual studio IDE

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-sam

Below is the error

```
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Consult https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/python3/ for mitigation steps.

This system supports the C.UTF-8 locale which is recommended.
You might be able to resolve your issue by exporting the
following environment variables:

export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

So this error occurs while using AWS visual studio shortcut to deploy sam, I have tried setting above value for LC_ALL and LANG

```
echo $LC_ALL 
C.UTF-8
echo $LANG
C.UTF-8
```